# Retrieving Snapshot HTML for Google

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, seo

So I am using `AJAX` to call a server file which uses WordPress to populate a `pages` content and return.  Which I than use to populate fields.  Now what I am confused about is, how do I create the snapshot and what do I have to do to make google know I am creating one besides `#!` also why do I do this?  The `escaped_fragments` are a little unclear to and hope I could get a more detailed explanation.  Does anyone have any tutorials that walk you through this process similar to what I am doing?

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google's crawlers don't typically run your JavaScript.  They hit your page, scrape your HTML, and move on.  This is much more efficient than loading your page and all of its resources, running your JavaScript, guessing at when everything finished loading, and then scraping data out of the DOM.

If your site uses AJAX to populate the page with content, this is a problem for Google and others.  Your page is effectively empty... void of any content... in its HTML state.  It requires your JavaScript to fill it in.  Since the crawlers don't run your JavaScript, your page isn't all that useful to the crawler.

These days, there are an awful lot of sites that blend the line between web-based applications and content-driven sites.  These sites (like yours) require client-side code to run to get the content.  Google doesn't have the resources to do this on every site they encountered, but they did provide an option.  That's the [info you found about escaped anchor fragments](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification).

Google has given you the opportunity to do the work of scraping the full finished DOM for them.  They have put the CPU and memory burden of running your JavaScript back on you.  You can signify to Google that this is encouraged by using links with `#!`.  Google sees this and knows that they can then request the same page, but convert everything after `#!` (which isn't sent to the server) to `?_escaped_fragment_=` and make a request to your server.  At this point, your server should generated a snapshot of the complete finished DOM, after JavaScript has ran.

The good news is that these days you don't have to hack a lot of code in place to do it.  I've written a server to do this using PhantomJS.  (I'm trying to get permission to open the source code up, but it's in legal limbo, sorry!)  Basically, PhantomJS is a full webkit web browser but it runs without a GUI.  You can [use PhantomJS to load your site](http://phantomjs.org/documentation/), run all the JavaScript, and then when its ready scrape the HTML back out of the page and send **that** version to Google.  This doesn't require you to do anything special, other than fix your routing to point requests with `_escaped_fragment_` at your snapshot server.

You can do this in about 20 lines of code.  PhantomJS even has a mini web server built into it, but they recommend not using it for production code.

I hope this helps clear up some confusion!

Comment: Brad this does help.  Do you have any helpful resources on creating the code to make sure google runs and returns the HTML snapshot?  Also what do you recommend me doing in this case?  Is it worth figuring out to make this google seo compliant or is it better to move on to more traditional ways?  I really don't want to do that because I know I have the skill and knowledge to create this easily.  Its just a matter of the understanding to what I need to do to make this work with Google.  Its a little unclear about my specific case.  Also to note I am using a AJAX call to server and not using a

Comment: link to change the URL and I just realized this is probably a problem.  What I mean is.  When they click on the event start, it is not a `a href` it is a `div` that contains a page code along with that div that my JQuery function picks up and sends via `AJAX`.  Which brings me to another question, I probbaly have to make sure I am using `#!` with links and I would'nt be able to rely on `window.location.hash = '#!key_page='+key_page+'';` to make it work with google?

Comment: Google doesn't run and return anything.  It's your server's responsibility to run your page and return the DOM snapshot to Google.  If you use links with `#!`, this indicates to Google that they should used the `_escaped_fragment_`.  From there, you just need to set up routes on your server to look for `_escaped_fragment_` to utilize your server.  My suggestion to you is to use what is best for your site.  If AJAX is core to your functionality, use a shapshot server.  If you can rework your page to function in a traditional manner, that would be best.

Comment: And yes, for Google to know about those links, you would need to link to the anchor fragments and not simply change them with JavaScript.

Comment: do you have any source or helpful docs on the server end `PHP` is what I am using.  Heres what I am doing, AJAX files the function to a `PHP` file which retrieves a `WordPress` page through their function `get_page_by_title` which gets stored in a response variable and than I use `Json_encode()` to echo it back out for pickup.  Now within this section how would I, using the `_escaped_fragment_` retrieve that data and give it back to Google?  This is the main part I am trying to get cleared up.  Like I said if you have anything that is really explanation based and gives great examples

Comment: Sounds like what you should be doing is not using AJAX at all...  but using PHP to echo that data directly in the page.  For the escaped anchor fragment, it doesn't matter what server-side and client-side technologies you're using as long as you return that DOM snapshot.  But from your description, it doesn't sound like you actually need AJAX at all.

Comment: I know but for the sake of functionality of wht I am accomplishing I need it.  So that brings me to my next question, how do I work with creating a HTML Snapshot?

Comment: @DavidBiga The easiest way is to build a snapshot server, using something like PhantomJS.  If you look at its documentation, you can see how to get the DOM contents after your page has loaded.  It's all scriptable with JavaScript.  In the Google documentation, there is reference to a Java snapshot server as well.